# How does one unlock the The Rubium Tech Upgrade

Tags: starbound

How can I unlock the Rubium Tech Upgrade in the robotic crafting table ?
I have everything I need to craft it but it just won't appear. Do I need to craft all the other tech upgrades before I can see it ? Is there another step I need to complete before seeing it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Tech Upgrades need to be crafted and used in order. Durasteel unlocks Aegisalt, which unlocks Ferozium, which unlocks Cerulium, which unlocks Violium, which unlocks Rubium, which unlocks Impervium gear.

The main reason for this, is that the tech upgrades (and all of Sector X) are currently just placeholders, since the latter half of the game hasn't really been built properly yet. Restricting the build order of the tech upgrades is, as of right now, the only thing preventing a player from jumping straight to top-tier stuff right away upon reaching Sector X.